# Creating an API searchbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a searchbar using JavaScript code that will help me search for a particular data from my database, but instead of bringing what's related to my search, it brings out all the data in my database.

## This is the JavaScript code

```
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const searchTerm = 
    document.getElementById('searchInput').value;
    fetch(`http://localhost:7007/search?q=${encodeURIComponent(searchTerm)}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        if(data['error'] !== true){
            console.log(data)
            console.log("No errors detected")
            data.forEach(found => {
            newNews(found);
            });
        }else{
            alert(result['message'])
        } 
    })
    .catch(error => {console.error('Error fetching data:',error);
});   
});
```

## This is the input in the html

```
 <form>
    <div class="for">
        <i id="ico" class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
        <input class="input" id="searchInput" type="text" placeholder="SEARCH ANY NEWS" style="width: 100%; border-left: none;">
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you sure that `data` is an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)? We need more information though.

Comment: You need to debug this. Both client side and server side. Make sure that parameter is passed to your server and that server takes corresponding filter into account.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please check searchInput value on client side.

```
const searchTerm = 
    document.getElementById('searchInput').value;
console.log(searchTerm);
```

2. Please check if the q param is correct on server side.
   for ex: if you use php code

```
$q = $_GET['q'];
echo $q;
```

3. If all is correct, please check query on server side.
   for ex: if you use mysql

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE key like '%{$q}%'
```

And check the query result on server side.

I think that you should prevent submit.

```
.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    ....
    return false;
});
```